# SQL for Microsoft Access 2013

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I am trying to get a count of customers who return for additional services that takes into account a comparison of assessment scores prior to the service, grouped by the type of Service.  (Ultimately, I also want to be able to ignore returns that are within a month of the orginal service, but I'm pretty sure I can get that wrinkle sorted myself)

When counting results for a particular service, it should look at returns to any service type, not just the original service type. (Edit: *It should also look at all future returns, not just the next or the most recent *).

It does not need to be run often, but there are 15000+ lines of data and computational resources are limited by an underpowered machine (this is for a nonprofit organization), so efficiency would be nice but not absolutely needed.

Sample Data

```
ServiceTable

CustomerID  Service  Date   ScoreBefore

   A    Service1    1/1/2017    1
   A    Service2    1/3/2017    1
   A    Service1    1/1/2018    4
   B    Service3    3/1/2018    3
   B    Service1    6/1/2018    1
   B    Service1    6/2/2018    1
   C    Service2    1/1/2019    4
   C    Service2    6/1/2019    1
```

Results should be (not taking into account the date padding option):

```
Service1
  ReturnedWorse 0
  ReturnedSame  2
  ReturnedBetter 1

Service2
  ReturnedWorse 1
  ReturnedSame 0
  ReturnedBetter 1

Service3
  ReturnedWorse 2
```

So far, I have tried creating make table queries that could then be queried to get the aggregate info, but I am a bit stuck and suspect there may be a better route.

What I have tried:

```
SELECT CustomerID, Service, Date, ScoreBefore INTO ReturnedWorse
FROM ServiceTable AS FirstStay
WHERE ((((SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM ServiceTable AS SecondStay
WHERE FirstStay.CustomerID=SecondStay.CustomerID
AND
FirstStay.ScoreBefore> SecondStay.ScoreBefore
AND
SecondStay.Date > FirstStay.Date))));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please explain how `Service1` has a count of 1 `ReturnedBetter` ? As per my understanding of the question, there are two occurences of customers returning after buying this service, and in both the score is even.

Comment: Also, `Service3`  should have just 1 `ReturnedWorse` instead of 2 - it has only one entry in your table.

Comment: Customer A returns twice, once to the same service and once to a different service. On his second return his score is 4 compare to 1.  The customer who used service3 returne twice, both with the same score.   The description admittedly should have been clearer (I added an edit) but it might help to think of them as related services within a single organization and it matters how customers return to the organization in any function and how many times they return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would have been easier to do with window functions, but they are not available in ms-access.

Here is a query that solves my understanding of your question :

- `t0`: pick a record in the table (a customer buying a service)
- `t1` : pull out the record  corresponding to the *next* time the same customer contracted any service with an `INNER JOIN` and a correlated subquery (if there is no such record, the initial record is not taken into account)
- compare the score of the previous record to the current one
- group the results by service id

You can see it in action in [this db fiddlde](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/koowdwcJeLKewrypSifWbL/0). The results are slightly different from your expectation (see my comments)... but they are consistent with the above explanation ; you might want to adapt some of the rules to match your exact expected result, using the same principles.

```
SELECT
    t0.service,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t1.scorebefore < t0.scorebefore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ReturnedWorse,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t1.scorebefore = t0.scorebefore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ReturnedSame,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t1.scorebefore > t0.scorebefore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ReturnedBetter
FROM 
    mytable t0
    INNER JOIN mytable t1
        ON  t0.customerid = t1.customerid
        AND t0.date < t1.date
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            from mytable 
            WHERE
                customerid = t1.customerid 
                AND date < t1.date
                AND date > t0.date
        )
GROUP BY t0.service
```

```
| service  | ReturnedWorse | ReturnedSame | ReturnedBetter |
| -------- | ------------- | ------------ | -------------- |
| Service1 | 0             | 2            | 0              |
| Service2 | 1             | 0            | 1              |
| Service3 | 1             | 0            | 0              |
```

---

From your comments, I understand that you want to take into account *all* future returns and not only the next one. This eliminates the need for a correlatead subquery, and actually yields your expected output. See [this db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/koowdwcJeLKewrypSifWbL/1) :

```
SELECT
    t0.service,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t1.scorebefore < t0.scorebefore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ReturnedWorse,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t1.scorebefore = t0.scorebefore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ReturnedSame,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t1.scorebefore > t0.scorebefore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ReturnedBetter
FROM 
    mytable t0
    INNER JOIN mytable t1
        ON  t0.customerid = t1.customerid
        -- AND t0.service = t1.service
        AND t0.date < t1.date
GROUP BY t0.service
```

```
| service  | ReturnedWorse | ReturnedSame | ReturnedBetter |
| -------- | ------------- | ------------ | -------------- |
| Service1 | 0             | 2            | 1              |
| Service2 | 1             | 0            | 1              |
| Service3 | 2             | 0            | 0              |
```

Comment: This seems like a much more promising account, but the results aren't quite right. Client A used service1 and then returned twice, once the same and once better. It looks like this code will only catch the first return, but I was trying to count all of them. It is a good reminder to rethink if that is what I really want, but for now I believe it is. I want to know how whether the client who used service1 ever returned worse etc.

Comment: @Ima_Pseudonym : got it ! Answer updated, indeed this yields your expected results.

Comment: Thanks! Almost makes me excited to go into work tomorrow and try it out.

Comment: As Access 2013 doesn't use CASE, the code for the SUM expressions should be SUM (IIF ([t1.scorebefore] < [t0.scorebefore],1,0))   etc.   For more complex expressions, SWITCH would avoid embedded IIFs, but the IIFs work fine here.